# Hydro release for Raring

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got ubuntu 13 and I want to start ROS development.  Any update on hydro release. right now I'm just reading tutorials and twiddling my thumbs waiting for the release.  should I just go ahead and work on compiling it now? or is it just a matter of days before the official release.  (does it have to do with the DARPA challenge? or something?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65364/hydro-release-for-raring/) by [AwokeKnowing](https://answers.ros.org/users/5171/awokeknowing/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Despite the fact that Hydro has not yet released (which might be about one more month) there are already Debian packages available for Raring. Please see the status page (columns HbinR32 and HbinR64) for whats available already: http://ros.org/debbuild/hydro.html

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AwokeKnowing](https://answers.ros.org/users/5171/awokeknowing/) on 2013-06-18**:
I did see that page, but I notice ros-base  was red. Is that not a problem?  If not, what's the command to install the full hydro and whatever version of gazebo works with it?  I would really appreciate your help. (I'm on ubuntu Raring 32 bit)

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-06-18**:
ros-base (as well as other variants) is not yet available since not all packages have been released into hydro by now. It is each packages maintainers responsibility to perform that release. You can install any package which is already available (e.g. apt-get install ros-hydro-*).

**Comment by [AwokeKnowing](https://answers.ros.org/users/5171/awokeknowing/) on 2013-06-18**:
Ok, thanks.  I'll try it tonight.